# call another application activity from different application activity?

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("another_app_package_name","another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that_package");

startActivity(intent);
```

getting **ActivityNotFoundException** ?

How to solve this problem? This problem posted earlier as well but no solution.I manifest file of application whose activity to be called i have used intent filter as well.

`Activity to be called by some other application's activity`

```
<activity 
     android:name="com.example.custompermission.PrivActivity">
     android:permission="abc.permission.STARTMYACTIVITY">
     <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: are you sure you can do that? i dont think you can do this directly. You can connect them through a broadcast, but like that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
 intent.setClassName(another_app_package_name.this,another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that_package.class);
```

startActivity(intent);

and in manifest.xml add this

```
      <activity  android:name="another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that__package"   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In  manifest file you  do like this:

```
<activity  android:name="another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that__package"></activity>
```

you should add the activity in manifest file, which you are tried to called from first activity.

you  need to add both the activities in manifest file: 
for ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (HomePage.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(intent);

in manifest: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name =".Second"></activity>
    </application>
```

Once, clean the project and run.

Comment: i have added activity to be called in manifest file still getting ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Still your problem was not solveble? Please post the intent code, which one you are using for calling the activity and also manifest declaration... error from logcat also..